# Big integer operation returning an array in JS

Tags: javascript, libraries, biginteger

I'm using this js library to work with big integers: http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js and the problem is that when I perform some operation like mult(A, powMod(B, e, N)) where A, B, e and N are big integers I get an array instead a big integer... then when I want to operate with this result I can't do it like It is a big integer. How can I trasnform this array in a big integer?

Do you know some big integer libraries for javascript that have powMod and InverMod methods?

Comment: This question is considered off-topic because you're asking us to find a library or other off-site resource.

Comment: Regarding why they return arrays, to quote the comments of the code you linked - *"A bigInt is an array of integers storing the value in chunks of bpe bits, little endian (buff[0] is the least significant word). Negative bigInts are stored two's complement.  Almost all the functions treat bigInts as nonnegative.  The few that view them as two's complement say so in their comments."* Seems a reasonable enough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The array is the bigInt, and it is able to be operated on as such using the functions available in the library.  If you want to be able to see it in a human-readable format, use the bigInt2str function.

```
<script>
var A = randBigInt(100,1);
var B = randBigInt(100,1);
var e = randBigInt(100,1);
var N = randBigInt(100,1);
var mult, x;
console.log('A =  ' + A); // A =  4145,12807,14234,10758,3424,5601,901,0
console.log('B =  ' + B); // B =  8476,8451,3441,15572,3002,10012,1000,0
console.log('e =  ' + e); // e =  3792,11382,3645,6320,9155,11401,789,0
console.log('N =  ' + N); // N =  5401,1700,6760,6147,11285,5907,837,0
mult = mult(A, powMod(B, e, N)); // the operation works
console.log('mult =  ' + mult); // mult =  24610,5611,13200,16143,988,8897,7049,13093,30523,11847,495,29557,22316,2,0
x = add(mult,N); // the operation works
console.log('x =  ' + x); // x =  30011,7311,19960,22290,12273,14804,7886,13093,30523,11847,495,29557,22316,2,0

console.log('mult as string, base 10: ' + bigInt2str(mult,10)); // 291979269279106415301425615088143991732473941997421745796392
console.log('x as string, base 10: ' + bigInt2str(x,10));       // 291979269279106415301425615088815343267840898748372641292627
</script>
```